# Synchronous queries for filling up an object

Tags: mongodb, asynchronous, restify

I have a project that use Restify, Node.js and MongoDB. It's a little project for testing Restify where I have some articles with some comments on them.

I'm actually trying to create a route that take the title of an article and return all the articles with the same name (Some article have exactly the same name) and associate with them the comments.

So globally, I have done that :

```
server.get('/articles/title/:title', (req, res, next) => {
    Article.find({'title': req.params.title}, (err,articles) => {
        if(err) {
            return next(new errors.InvalidContentError(err.errors.name.message));
        }
        for(var i=0;i<articles.length;i++) {
            Comment.find({'article': articles[i]._id}, (err, comments) => {
                articles[i]["link"] = comments;
            });
        }
        res.send(articles);
        next();
    });
});
```

But this code does not work because Comment.find is asynchronous.

So my question, how can I make this code synchronous ? I have looked in the documentation but I dont find something that could really help me. I'm not even sure that my way of thinking is the good one for achieving that.

Comment: Use the async library and check out the eachSeries function.

Answer (score 1):

you are doing it in wrong way, if you are using "mongoose" library you can use the `populate()` method to have comments and post together,
[take a look this mongoose documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

if you are doing raw mongo query, then you need use `$lookup` aggregation
[$look up documenation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html)

your matching posts and comments could be fetched all together efficiently by above methods.

Comment: Thank shahin mahmud, I'm indeed using mongoose. I know now how to populate a ref to the parent from children. But is it possible to get the children from the parent if they are not any ref to them ? I mean, I can fetch all the articles and since I know their id, I can get the comments they are associated with. I know how to do that with PHP and Mysql but I'm quite confuse with mongoose

Answer (score 0):

```
db.yourparent_table.aggregate([
// to split each of array element
{ "$unwind": "$your_children_field" },

{ "$lookup": {
   "from": "yourparent_table",
   "localField": "your_children_field",
   "foreignField": "_id",
   "as": "comments"
}},
```

])

Comment: i just gave you an idea about how you do aggregation do things like this.
To get the full solution of your problem you have "$match" first, do the above step, then again "$group_by" everything so you can add the sparsed comments into each articles array again. Give it a look at monog aggregation framework